# How to change "for" into a multithreaded pool in python

Tags: python, multithreading

So I made this program that I want to loop for ever until closed. So at the moment I use this piece of code;

```
while True:
  a = start();
  for aaa in a:
    check(a[aaa], 0)
```

But that is pretty slow. How can I multithread this using this (this is my try, it's incorrect ofcourse);

```
pool = ThreadPool(threads)
results = pool.map(check, a, 0)
```

I tried that code, with `threads = 1`. And it just gave nothing. Could anyone help me with this?

==== EDIT ====

Start function;

```
def start():
    global a
    url = "URL_WAS_HERE" // receives a json like {"a":56564356, "b":654653453} etc. etc.
    r = requests.get(url)
    a = json.loads(r.text)
    return a
```

Check function;

```
def check(idd, tries):
  global checked
  global snipe
  global notworking
  if tries < 1:
    checked = checked+1
    url = "URL_WAS_HERE"+str(idd) // Receives json with extra information about the id
    r = requests.get(url)
    try:
        b = json.loads(r.text)
        if b['rap'] > b['best_price']:
            difference = b['rap']-b['best_price'];
            print(str(idd)+" has a "+str(difference)+ "R$ difference. Price: "+str(b['best_price'])+" //\\ Rap: "+str(b['rap']))
            snipe = snipe+1

    except:
        time.sleep(1)
        tries = tries+1
        notworking = notworking+1
        check(idd, tries)
  settitle("Snipes; "+str(snipe)+" //\\ Checked; "+str(checked)+" //\\ Errors; "+str(notworking))
```

I hope this helps a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps start by using a documented object, [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor). `ThreadPool` is an undocumented language feature.

The docs offer minimal examples to get you started. For your example try the following construction:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

values_to_test = a()
result_container = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:  # set `max_workers` as appropriate
    pool = {executor.submit(check, val, tries=0): val for val in values_to_test}

    for future in as_completed(pool):
        try:
            result_container.append(future.result())
        except:
            pass  # handle exceptions here
```

If you are set on using the `map` method, you cannot pass `0` as an argument because it is not an iterable; see the method [signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map).